# Connected component in a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$ (if necessary, locally of finite type).  Let $E$ be a connected component of $X$.  Then $E$ is closed.  For example, $X$ could be a group scheme over $k$, and $E = X^0$ the connected component of the identity point in $X$.

There are many closed subscheme structures one can place on $E$.

I've seen notes that mention the possibility of $E$ being **geometrically connected**.  A scheme $Y$ over $k$ is said to be geometrically connected if $Y \times_k \overline{k}$ is connected.  However, $E$ is just a closed subset of $X$, not yet a scheme.

When people talk about $E$ being geometrically connected, are they saying with respect to a fixed closed subscheme structure on $E$?  Or is it the case that the underlying space of $E \times_k \overline{k}$ does not depend on the choice of closed subscheme structure on $E$?

In the case where $X = \textrm{Spec } A$ is affine, it seems what I am doing is comparing the spectra of $A/I \otimes_k \overline{k}$ and $A/\sqrt{I} \otimes_k \overline{k}$.

We can identify $A/I \otimes_k \overline{k} = A \otimes_k \overline{k}/(I \otimes \overline{k})$, and the same for $\sqrt{I}$.  I believe that the span of $I$ and $\sqrt{I}$ in $A \otimes_k \overline{k}$ are ideals with the same radical, which tells me that the prime spectra of $A/I \otimes_k \overline{k}$ and $A/\sqrt{I} \otimes_k \overline{k}$ are the same topological space.  So if $X$ is affine, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

$E$ is not just a closed subset. It is also an open subset, so it inherits a scheme structure by restricting the scheme structure from $X$.

Comment: Why is $E$ open?

Comment: @D_S: you're right that $E$ need not be open in general. But for example if $X$ is finite type over a field, it has finitely many connected components, so each one is open since it is the complement of a finite union of closed sets (the other components).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a connected component of a scheme comes with a canonical scheme structure, see: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04PV